# fluctuating ping/latency only to a certain ISP

Tags: networking, ping, traceroute

Pretty much the title. There's an ISP server that located 200miles away from my location. Once the packets cross their network, it fluctuates from 40ms to 120ms back and forth and rarely happen to be stable, only occasionally. This problem doesn't happen to any other servers. Only this particular ISP. And i'm afraid that it'll affect some real-time applications and games too. Is this normal?